# state list drop down error in virtuemart registration

Tags: php, joomla2.5, virtuemart

States are not displaying on virtuemart registration page when a country(in my case India) is selected.
There is following javascript error while the page loads - -

$("...").vm2front is not a function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is dedicated to many programming languages. Please add an appropriate language, framework or technology tag to your questions to get relevant answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a quick solution for this problem and would like to share it with all of us - -

In the file /administrator/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/config.php around the line 1130 commented the code - -

**/*
        if($app->isSite()){

            return;

        }
          */**

and then in the file /components/com_virtuemart/views/user/tmpl/edit_address.php around line 34 added the code 
 **< script src="components/com_virtuemart/assets/js/vmsite.js" type="text/javascript" />**
P.S Don't forget to remove the spaces from script tags.
This solved my problem and of course you can remove the already added vmsite.js file included for this page.

Thanx,
Pramod